# Connect to Amazon web services SQS (Simple Queue service) using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I was wondering if somebody here knows how I can connect to AWS SQS using Python? Do I need a public Url?

Could someone provide a simple code example on how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use [`boto`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/sqs-example-using-queues.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code for pushing messages into SQS (sorry, using boto rather than the recommended boto3):

```
import boto, boto.sqs
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from optparse import OptionParser

# Parse command line
parser = OptionParser()
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

# Send to SQS
q_conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-2")

q = q_conn.get_queue('cheese-queue')
if q==None:
  print "No queue!"
else:
  m = Message()
  m.set_body(args[0])
  q.write(m)
  print args[0] + ' pushed to Queue'
```

Here's some sample code to read from SQS:

```
import boto, boto.sqs
from boto.sqs.message import Message

# Connect to Queue
q_conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-2")
q = q_conn.get_queue('cheese-queue')

# Get a message
m = q.read(visibility_timeout=15)
if m == None:
  print "No message!"
else:
  print m.get_body()
  q.delete_message(m)
```

Comment: Thanks for code! Can i for example write this in pycharm or do i need to use a python shell?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, use `boto`:

> ```
> import boto3
>
> # Create SQS client
> sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
>
> # List SQS queues
> response = sqs.list_queues()
>
> print(response['QueueUrls'])
> ```

Documentation [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/sqs-example-using-queues.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Im new to this forum, so if i did something wrong im sorry :)

Comment: Still having problems retrieving messages from the SQS tho.. Have followed all guides installing boto3, aws cli and so on.. I am coding inside pycharm and i dont get any errors.. :/